# How to evaluate a stream line by line

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am trying to avoid creating any new files to store output in order to minimize the risk of overwriting something in a directory with the same name. I am trying to just evaluate each line in a stream with a pipe instead of outputting to a file and then using a `while read line do done < file` loop. Something like:

```
echo -e "1\n2\n3\n4\n5" | #evaluate current line separately#
```

Could I somehow read each line into an array and then evaluate the elements in the array? or is there a better way to avoid accidentally overwriting files?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In `bash`, the common way is to use the Process Substitution:

```
while read line ; do
    ...
done < <( commands producing the input)
```

Comment: Is there a portable way to do this?  The `< <( command ...)` syntax is not supported in ksh.

Comment: What's wrong with this?  command_producing_input |while read line; do ...; done

Comment: @MarkEdgar: Try changing or setting a variable in the loop body.

Answer (score 4):

You were halfway there...

```
echo -e "1\n2\n3\n4\n5" | while read line; do
    ...
done
```

Note that bash runs each part of the pipeline in a separate process, and any variables defined there will not persist after that block.  (ksh93 will preserve them, as the loop will run in the current shell process.)

Comment: Process substitution avoids that problem. Also, Bash 4.2 has `shopt -s lastpipe`.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid overwriting files by using `mktemp` or `tempfile` to create temporary files with unique names. However, I would use process substitution as in choroba's answer.